# After 15 times firebase isn't sending any password reset option in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to send a password reset link to my account through firebase in android studio but after testing it 15 times now no mails are going into my account and it's showing mail cannot be sent Can anyone help me Below is the code which i have used.

`FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;`
  `firebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail("rohan98@gmail.com");`

Is this my own perception or the firebase has some limitations upto which it can send mails to a single mail ID.

Comment: Please contact Firebase support to troubleshoot things that might be going wrong in your project.  Stack Overflow is not appropriate for support questions.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Try sending using firebase console!